# How to exclude just one folder from included parent folder within tsconfig.js

Tags: typescript, tsconfig

Suppose you have a file structure as follows

```
/src
    utils/ <many .ts files>
    components/ <many .ts files>
    ...
    nodejs/ <many .ts files>
```

Now, because I'm working on a web project I would like to import all of those except the `nodejs` one. I tried for example

```
"include": [
    "src/**/*.ts"
],
"exclude": [
    "src/nodejs/**/*.ts"
]
```

But then the `nodejs` folder is still included. I can only get this to work if I include each folder separately, like this

```
"include": [
    "src/utils/*/**.ts"
    "src/components/**/*.ts"
    ...
],
```

In my case this list is not extremely long, but long enough for me not to like this solution. And it feels like there should be a better alternative. Any suggestions?

Comment: Ai thnx, but that was a typo in my post :)

Comment: Can you use regular expression like folder name not equal to node in your include block?

Comment: You should be able to exclude a folder instead of files: `"exclude": [ "src/nodejs" ]`

Comment: The problem is that if I use that `exclude` I also have to do **"includes": [ "src/**/*.ts" ]"** and then it seems that the exclude is ignored

Comment: I assume you are not using the `files` property is that correct?

Comment: I do, it contains two files ** "src/main.ts", "src/polyfills.ts"**

Comment: Do those two files reference any files in the `src/nodejs` folder?

Comment: nope, they are completely independent. The files I want to include (and exclude) live inside in the node_modules folder